# Person who doesn't want to listen to others' personal feelings

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the equivalent word for a *person who doesn't want to hear/listen others' personal feelings/information*. If not, the equivalent word for a *person who are stubborn in listening to others' feelings/information*.

Opposite to the meaning of the word **reticent**.

Comment: Feelings are something you feel, not something you can listen to. You can listen to other people _talking about_ their feelings, but the only way you can listen to the feelings themselves is if they are your own and you're using it in the same way that “Listen to your heart” is used, i.e., to search your feelings and act in accordance with them.

Comment: You will have to be way more specific. What is the context? What is the sentence you want to use it in? What is the part of speech you're after? Why and to what end does the person not care about others' feelings? Is it because they are bored, autistic, egoistic? Have you looked up any of these words in a thesaurus? What did it say? Why did that not suit you?

Comment: I will be framing the sentence based on the words suggested here. And I don't know, the person may be bored, autistic or egoistic. No, I didn't look up in thesaurus, It shows words similar to the words I type in. But I am not easily able to look up the words with the expected meaning of my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides already-mentioned *[insensitive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insensitive#Adjective)*, consider  *[callous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/callous#Adjective)* (“Emotionally hardened; unfeeling and indifferent to the suffering/feelings of others”) and *[hardened](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hardened#Adjective)* (“Unfeeling or lacking emotion due to experience; callous”), and *[heartless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heartless#Adjective)* (“Without a heart; specifically, **without feeling, emotion, or concern for others; uncaring**”).

On another tack, consider   *[self-centered](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-centered#Adjective)* (“Of a person, egotistically obsessed with himself or herself”) and  *[self-absorbed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-absorbed#Adjective)* (“Overly concerned about oneself, to the point of **ignoring the feelings of others**”).

Answer (score 2):

[Insensitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insensitive) : ( from M-W)

> - showing that you do not know or care about the feelings of other people
> - not responding to or caring about problems, changes, or needs.

also the expressions:

[be as hard as nails](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Tape) :

> - to have no feelings or sympathy for other people She'll be good in business - she's as hard as nails.

[Hard-boiled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard-boiled):

> - tough and callous by virtue of experience.

*Sensitive or carin*g can be two obvious antonyms.